# Should a delegate go through a controller to get the model?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller

Trying to figure out the MVC-concept.

I have a NSCustomView that implements drawRect:, which is based on a delegate specified in the controller of the custom view.  My question is, should the delegate point to the model's controller, or is it ok to point the delegate directly to the model?

Should the NSCustomView ask the NSWindowController, to ask the Model's Controller, to ask the model for the data?  Seems like there are too many layers to a "proper" MVC design.

Comment: Read [MVC as a Compound Design Pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW22). Although it is quite possible to make the Model and the View communicate directly, in the Cocoa version of MVC, they always communicate through the Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More often than not, the delegate **is** the view controller, or fits into a controller-type role. If that's not your situation, it'll help if you explain what's going on in greater detail.

Comment: Here's what I'm not understanding. If I'm supposed to have complete separation between M V and C. What in the app is supposed to "own" the M part? Does the C own the M?  What creates the M part? Right now I have my C create the M, but this is causing problems because I'm trying to archive the data, which isn't playing well because it also archives the C.

Comment: You have a fair bit of freedom in that respect, and much depends on your app design. For example, iOS apps often don't have any sense of a document, so the model may be created by the app delegate and then passed along to the controllers as necessary. Desktop apps are more likely to work with documents, and in that case it might be the document that creates the model, and the app delegate just creates documents in response to New and Open commands.

Comment: So in the desktop example, does the Document create the view instance too?  I seem to be missing something.  I looked at the TextEdit example, but not seeing how the MVC are allocated and where they're kept.  I have a "document-based" desktop app.  But each project is comprised of multiple NSWindowControllers.

Comment: See `-[Document makeWindowControllers]` in the TextEdit source. That instantiates a DocumentWindowController, which loads a window from a nib. That's the view. Then look at `-[Document init]` and `-[Document readFromURL:ofType:encoding:ignoreRTF:]` and notice how the documents NSTextStorage object is created and populated with data; that's the model. The document itself and the document window controller play controller roles.

Comment: That's really odd because NSDocument (model/data) owns the WindowController (controller), which in turn owns the nib instance (view).

Comment: I think you misunderstand. It's not that there can't be relationships between model and controller, or controller and view. The idea is to avoid dependencies between view and model and vice versa, so that they can each be modified without impacting the other. NSDocument better fits into the controller category than the model category. Read [The Role of NSDocument](http://tinyurl.com/3vzuh55).